# Error importing Eclipse project into workspace

Tags: eclipse

[image]I am trying to import an existing running project into another eclipse environment in different system . I followed to export the file as FIle -->export-->General-->File System . and compressed the file. and in other system extracted the zip file and imported as File-->import --> existing projects into work space and facing the following error.

org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'bundleVersionHistory' not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse FeatureNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824632/eclipse-featurenotfoundexception)

Comment: tried these, but found with no luck on this.

Comment: not sure if this relates to any plug-in, u might want to share some more details as in what exactly have you tried, your eclipse versions etc .. might help others to get to the point

Comment: I have an eclipse customized workspace of SAP(SUP sybase unwired platform SP02) in cloud. Have developed a project in there(cloud). and have SP04 in my local system. I am trying to import the project generated in cloud to my local machine and facing this issue. With one of my friend importing in  the same SP4 in his local maching works fine.

Comment: Don't know how this happened. But moving the existing project from the current location to a new location and importing in a new workspace made it to work.

Comment: that's good to know .. why don't you put this as ans

Comment: I am not sure mark self answer as correct answer.