# Error while downloading 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
```

this is my code in vscode, how to solve this error (Error while downloading 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd')

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior requires an internet connection, your webapp won't startup without an internet connection. Besides,what exactly is the error message?

In addition, the version of your project facet needs to be consistent with the configuration of web.xml, otherwise an error will be reported. For example, what you want is **2.3**. You can check if it is the same later.
I also found another issue:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824632/eclipse-featurenotfoundexception), there may have the information you want. you can see if it is useful. Hope helpful.

Comment: Is there any update from you? Hope to hear from you that your question has been solved.