# Dynamic Web project Error "Loading descriptor"

Tags: eclipse

In the process of trying to build an android web service using Spring under Eclipse IDE, I need to create a Dynamic Web Project using Maven. The problem I am facing is an error " Loading descriptor for project has encountered a problem. I don't know how to solve this. Any input on that?

Comment: Sounds like an issue parsing xml. When do you get this error? When running the code?

Comment: when I first create the project, if I refresh..

Comment: It is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774278/eclipse-loading-descriptor-takes-ages

Comment: It is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774278/eclipse-loading-descriptor-takes-ages

Answer (score 14):

If you get the following exception:

> Loading descriptor for project has encountered a problem. [...]
>   Nullpointerexception

right after creating a project, then there are 2 possible causes (or at least that how it was for me, when I had this issue).

1) A **web.xml file is missing in your WebContent/WEB-INF folder** or was not created during project creation. (in the last window you have to check option "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor" in eclipse, otherwise eclipse won't generate that file)

If your project is already created, you can still *add a web.xml file into your **WEB-INF** directory*. Depending on your servlet version (e.g. 2.5) you have to use a different template which can be found on the net.

2) **Your Eclipse does not have all the necessary plugins for Dynamic Web projects**. 

You need to go to **Help** >> **Install new Software**
Select the site which corresponds to your eclipse version. (e.g. Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler )

Install:

1. JST Server UI
2. JST Web UI
3. JST Server Adapters
4. JST Server Adapters Extension
5. WST Server Adapters.

You may also need:

Eclipse Java EE Developer tools

Eclipse Java Web Developer tools

Java Server Faces tools or JSF tools

Eclipse faceted Project Framework

Eclipse faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement

Comment: missing web.xml doesn't give this descriptor error. its just missing plugin/facets, please check your references.

Comment: @aishu I listed that problem as one possible cause for that error. As the OP has stated: that error occured during creating a new project which could be either because the OP unchecked the auto-generation or did not have all necessary plugins for dynamic web projects

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. "Eclipse Java Web Developer tools" should be enough to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 1):

1. install Java EE web developer tools from Help >> "Install new Software".
2. check in project properties "Project Facets" should have proper check boxes enabled eg Dynamic Web Project etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but may be useful for others.
In web.xml there may be some attribute repated in web-app tag.
In my case xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" attribute in repeated in tag web-app.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Eclipse Java Development tools** from Help >> "Install new Software".